# How to write VBA code that works in multiple Office apps

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to write a single VBA code module that works on the three main Office Apps (Excel, PowerPoint, Word).

Because the object models are different in each app, if I write code that's specific for PowerPoint while in the Excel VBE, the project won't compile. The way to go first appears to be to use conditional compiler constants. But this still causes the VBE to spit out errors depending on which MSO app the VBE is currently being hosted in.

In the simplified example below, I want to add a picture to a sheet, slide or document, depending on which app the VBA code is being run from. If I try to compile it in Excel, the PowerPoint code doesn't compile (even though it's within a conditional compiler If...Then statement!) and vice-versa. How does one get round this without adding references to the other MSO apps (as this causes compatibility issues when distributing to different MSO versions)?

The way the compiler continues to look at code that should be effectively "commented out" by the conditional compiler constants is very odd/annoying behaviour!

```
' Set the compiler constant depending on which MSO app is hosting the VBE
' before saving as the respective .ppam/.xlam/.dotm add-in
#Const APP = "EXL"

Option Explicit

Dim curSlide As Integer
Dim curSheet As Integer

Public Sub InsertPicture()
    Dim oShp as Shape
    #If APP = "PPT" Then
        ' Do PowerPoint stuff
        ' The next 2 lines will throw "Invalid qualifier" and
        ' "Variable not defined" errors respectively when compiling in Excel.
        curSlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
        Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(curSlide).Shapes.AddPicture & _
            (filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)
    #ElseIf APP = "EXL" Then
        ' Do Excel stuff
        curSheet = ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet
        Set oShp = ActiveSheet.AddPicture(filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)
    #ElseIf APP = "WRD" Then
        ' Do Word stuff
    #End If
End Sub
```

Since I'm unable to answer my own question:

Expanding on your idea KazJaw, I think something like this may work, replacing the CreateObject function with GetObject (because the instance will already exist since the procedure is being called from within an add-in):

```
' CONDITIONAL COMPILER CONSTANTS
' Set this value before saving to .ppam, .xlam or .dotm
#Const APP = "EXL" ' Allowed Values : PPT, EXL or WRD

Sub One_Sub_For_Word_Excel_PP(filename As String, Optional SlideIndex as Integer)
    #If APP = "PPT" Then
        Dim appPPP As Object
        Set appPPT = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        appPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes.AddPicture & _
            (filename,msoFalse,msoTrue,0,0)
    #ElseIf APP = "EXL" Then
        Dim appEXL As Object
        Set appEXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        appEXL.ActiveSheet.AddPicture(filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)
    #ElseIf APP = "WRD" Then
        Dim appWRD As Object
        Set appWRD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        appWRD.ActiveDocument.AddPicture(filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)
    #End If
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest I can't imagine the situation I would like to use the solution you are trying to prepare. There is one option but will be very, very inefficient. Are you interested in such solution?

Comment: The situation is reflective of the way that many features in MSO are common across all apps. The one I am writing falls into exactly the same case in that I want the same feature to be available in 3 main MSO apps so yes, I am interested in a solution but when you say "very, very inefficient" what do you mean? For the programmer or the user or the machine?

Comment: Two additional options: Write a [COM add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141383(v=office.10).aspx), or on the `Auto_Open` event, programmatically ensure that references to each of the three libraries are enabled, that way it should compile. (I have done the latter with an application that runs in PPT or XLS)

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically set the application name based on the current application (instead of setting the APP constant)?  (Note: I have never written a COM Add-in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
Public AppName as String
Public App as Object
Sub One_Sub_For_Word_Excel_PP(filename As String, Optional SlideIndex as Integer)
    AppName = Application.Name
    Set App = Application
    Select Case AppName
        Case "Microsoft PowerPoint"
            App.ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes.AddPicture & _
                (filename,msoFalse,msoTrue,0,0)

        Case "Microsoft Excel"
            App.ActiveSheet.AddPicture(filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)

        Case "Microsoft Word"
            App.ActiveDocument.AddPicture(filename, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0)

      End Select
End Sub
```

Alternatively, write a COM Add-in.

Comment: Even better and much cleaner - no conditional compiler constants :-)
I should add that my original Excel and Word lines in the Case options are not correct but the overall solution works. Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment- I can't imagine the situation I would like to use the solution you are trying to prepare. However, there is one solution even you set lot's of limitations (including not setting references to other application libraries). Please keep in mind that such attempt will be not efficient and I would never recommend anything like this.

The following test subroutine works for all three applications: MS Word, MS PowerPoint, MS Excel. Additional information in comments inside the code.

```
Sub One_Sub_For_Word_Excel_PP()

    Dim XLS As Object
    Dim PP As Object
    Dim WRD As Object

    'this will open instances of all application- to avoid any errors
    Set XLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")


    'your code here
    'remember- do not use vba constants like msoFalse but use _
     their numeric values instead

    'simple test
    If Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then
        'do things only for excel
        Debug.Print XLS.Name
    ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft PowerPoint" Then
        'do things only for PP
        Debug.Print PP.Name
    Else
        'do things only for Word
        Debug.Print WRD.Name
    End If

    Set XLS = Nothing
    Set PP = Nothing
    Set WRD = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks KazJaw. I don't think this is what I need since it assumes that instances of all 3 MSO apps are to be created. What I need is a a solution that addresses the correct object model depending on the hosting MSO app. There is only ever one instance of the app and that is the one in which the code is running but the entire code will be saved in individual .ppam/.xlam/.dotm add-ins.

For example, how would you create a single code that adds a circle to a slide, sheet or document which can then sit inside a .ppam/.xlam/.dotm add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it

```
#Const APP = "EXL"

#If APP = "PPT" Then
```

etc.?

Comment: I think it's a combination of this and what KazJaw said and since I can't answer my own question, I've edit my original post to write what I think may work, thanks to both of you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Shimon Rachienko: Sorry, I disagree with your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the same code to be able to run from within any VBA-enabled app (but not necessarily to invoke other apps).  So ...

```
Sub One_Sub_To_Rule_Them_All()
' Modified version of KazJaw's previous post

    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = Application

    Select Case oApp.Name
        Case Is = "Microsoft Excel"
        'do things only for excel

        Case Is = "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        'do things only for PP, eg
           MsgBox oApp.ActivePresentation.Fullname

        Case Is = "Microsoft Word"
        ' do wordthings

        Case Is = "Visio or CorelDraw or Whatever"
        ' do whatever things

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Jumping up and down and waving hands and running around like headless chicken"

    End Select

    Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

All the same, I wouldn't do it this way.  Apart from the other objections, you need to treat the apps as objects in order for the code to compile, and when you do that, you toss out intellisense.  Not a trivial loss.  Sure, you can get around that by developing the Word part in Word, the PPT part in PPT ... but in that case, why not just make separate code modules?